# How do I use the output of one function for another function?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was making the code to extract information from the website.

And I wanted it to make for simple and try to organized in some function.

Now, I have a problem with using output of one function for another one.

```
def last_indeed_page():
    indeed_info = requests.get(url)
    indeed_soup = BeautifulSoup(indeed_info.text, "html.parser")
    pagination = indeed_soup.find("ul", {"class": "pagination-list"})
    pages = pagination.find_all("li")
    a = []
    for page in pages[:-1]:
        a.append(int(page.get_text()))
    last_page = a[-1]
    return last_page
```

I want to use this output **last_page** in next function.

```
def extract_indeed_job(last_page):
    jobs = []
    for n in range(last_page):
        print(f"Indeed scraping page:{n+1}")
        result = requests.get(f"{url}&start={n*LIMIT}")
        result_soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
        results = result_soup.find_all("a", {"class": "tapItem"})
        for result in results:
            job = extract_job(result)
            jobs.append(job)
        print(jobs)

extract_indeed_job(last_page)
```

But, the output of this functions is nothing. It doesn't give me a error but just nothing.
Which part do I have to change?

Comment: extract_indeed_job(last_indeed_page())?

Comment: Do I have to use that parentesis for last_indeed_page also???

Comment: Yes, since you are calling a function, the parentheses are required. I have written a more detailed answer with 2 alternatives so that you can choose whichever is more comfortable for you

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 functions: `last_indeed_page()`, `extract_indeed_job(last_page)`; and the output of `last_indeed_page` needs to be sent to `extract_indeed_job`.

There are 2 ways to do that.

1. you can either create a variable and then call the function:

```
last_page_variable = last_indeed_page()
extract_indeed_job(last_page_variable)
```

2. you can directly call the `last_indeed_page` function inside the `extract_indeed_job` function so that the value returned by the `last_indeed_page` function is passed into `extract_indeed_job`

```
extract_indeed_job(last_indeed_page())
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I have another question. 
If I want to run this code from another page. 
I have to import last_indeed_page() and extract_indeed_job(), right??

Comment: @SeowooJang can you explain what you mean by another page? If you mean another file; then you need to use `import thisfile` and then use the functions as `thisfile.last_indeed_page()` and `thisfile.extract_indeed_job(variable)`

Comment: I mean another file. sorry my explain was bad. 
okey. I asked you because I want to unite with another web scraping code. 
I am gonna use as your advice. thanks